# Does the existence of regular conditional measure follow from that of regular conditional distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

For more succinct description, I use the following abbreviations, i.e.,

- **RCPD**: Regular conditional probability distribution.
- **RCPM**: Regular conditional probability measure.

First are definitions 10.4.1. and 10.4.2. of **RCPM** from Bogachev's [Measure Theory](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-34514-5.pdf).

> **Definition 10.4.1.** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal B$ sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$. The **RCPM** on $\mathcal A$ given $\mathcal B$ is a map $M:\mathcal A \times \Omega \to [0, 1]$ such that
>
> - $M(\cdot, \omega)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal A$ for $\mathbb P$-a.e. $\omega \in \Omega$.
> - For every $A \in \mathcal A$, the map $M(A, \cdot)$ is $\mathcal B$-measurable.
> - For every $(A, B) \in \mathcal A \times \mathcal B$,
>   $$
>   \mathbb P[A \cap B] = \int_{B} M(A, \omega) \mathrm d \mathbb P (\omega).
>   $$

Sometimes, the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$ in **Definition 10.4.1.** is generated by a measurable function $f$. Then we have a generalization, i.e.,

> **Definition 10.4.2.** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{A}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $(X, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space, $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ measurable, and $\mu:=f _\sharp \mathbb P$. The **RCPM on $\mathcal A$ given $\mathcal B$** is a map $M:\mathcal A \times X \to [0, 1]$ such that
>
> - $M(\cdot, x)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal A$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$.
> - For every $A \in \mathcal A$, the map $M(A, \cdot)$ is $\mathcal B$-measurable.
> - For every $(A, B) \in \mathcal A \times \mathcal B$,
>   $$
>   \mathbb P[A \cap \{f \in B\}] = \int_{B} M(A, x) \mathrm d \mu (x).
>   $$

To get **Definition 10.4.1.** from **Definition 10.4.2.**, we set $X:=\Omega$ and $f$ the identity map. Next is the definition 2.28. of **RCPD** from Onno van Gaans's [Gradient flows in measure spaces](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/TA2011-gradient-mei11.pdf).

> **Definition 2.28.** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{A}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $(X, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space and $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ measurable. A **RCPD on $\mathcal B$ given $\mathcal{A}$** is a map $D: \mathcal{B} \times \Omega \rightarrow[0,1]$ such that
>
> - $D (\cdot, \omega)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}$ for $\mathbb{P}$-a.e. $\omega \in \Omega$.
> - For every $B \in \mathcal{B}$, the map $D (B, \cdot)$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.
> - For every $(A, B) \in \mathcal A \times \mathcal B$,
>   $$
>   \mathbb P [A \cap \{f \in B\}] = \int_A D(B, \omega) \mathrm d \mathbb P (x).
>   $$

It seems the definitions of **RCPM** and **RCPD** are very closely related, i.e.,

- $M$ is the **RCPM** on $\mathcal A$ given $\mathcal B$, while $D$ is the **RCPD** on $\mathcal B$ given $\mathcal{A}$.
- $\operatorname{dom} (M) = \mathcal A \times X$, while $\operatorname{dom} (D) = \mathcal B \times \Omega$. To "get" $D$ from $M$, we move forward from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$, and move backward from $X$ to $\Omega$.
- $M(A, \cdot)$ is $\mathcal B$-measurable, while $D (B, \cdot)$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.
- $$
  \int_{B} M(A, x) \mathrm d \mu (x) = \mathbb P [A \cap \{f \in B\}] = \int_A D(B, \omega) \mathrm d \mathbb P (x).
  $$

If $X$ is a Polish space and $\mathcal B$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then **RCPD** exists. I'm interested in disintegration theorem whose proof depends on the existence of **RCPM**.

> **My question:** Can we prove the existence of **RCPM** from that of **RCPD**?

Thank you so much for your elaboration.

Comment: Sad to get a downvote without any reason...